# PHP Symfony2 websocket client and responsiveness

Tags: php, symfony, websocket, ratchet

I have a symfony2 application that provides stock quotes to an HTML5 drawing library.

I want to start using a 3rd party service that using websockets provides realtime quotes, to do that I created a very simple websocket client using Ratchet Pawl, that will listen for quote updates and store it in the local cache for its usage when needed.

Basically I added to a controller the simple example code, the idea would be to have it in a service, but this is just for easier testing:

```
    \Ratchet\Client\connect('ws://echo.socketo.me:9000')->then(function($conn) {
    $conn->on('message', function($msg) use ($conn) {

          // update local cache with new quotes            
    });

    $conn->send('Hello World!');
}, function ($e) {
    echo "Could not connect: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
});
```

The deal is that works fine, but as it keeps listening further messages, all the rest of the application stops being responsive so I can't use any other endpoint of the app.

So, is it possible to keep a thread running constantly responding to the websocket updates?

Would the same happen when it's running on nginx in prod and I just see this becase app/console server:run doesn't supports multithreading?

What would be the best way to deal with this issue, I'm not very experienced on Symfony2 development.

Thanks for your help

Comment: when using a normal setup, if you run this in a command, so that it runs in a seperate php process, you should be fine. (i have a similar setup for a different service)